# Why does $\nabla \to ik$ when you Fourier transform?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

I am reading a text that describes the scattering of light by a particle with dielectric constant $\epsilon$

After a bit of maths starting from Maxwell's equations they obtain:

$$\nabla (\nabla \cdot E(r)) - \nabla^2E(r)=\mu_0\omega^2\epsilon(r)\cdot E(r)$$

then say "Fourier transforming with respect to $r$ gives (replace $\nabla$ by $ik$):"

$$[k^2 \hat{I}-kk]\cdot E(k) = \mu_0 \omega^2 \int \epsilon(r) \cdot E(r)  \exp(-ik \cdot r) \,\mathrm{d}r$$

I don't understand why all $\nabla$ have turned into $ik$? Is there any way to visualize why this can be done?

Comment: Actually perform the Fourier transform. You will see what happens.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877966/fourier-transform-of-poisson-equation/877967#877967

Comment: Thanks guys, that example on mathexchange did it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to understand this is to start simply:
Consider a function $f(x)$. Now, let's try to take the Fourier transform of its derivative $f'(x)$. Just use the definition of the Fourier transform: 
$$\mathscr{F}(f'(x))(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int dx\ e^{-ikx}f'(x) $$
and now use integration by parts (assuming $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, a typical assumption in this context).

Comment: Thanks, this and the math exchange example shows me why this is the case. Very clean. Out of interest, I understand the physical significance of $\nabla$ in real space, but in Fourier space (the $ik$), is it just now instead of 'local rate of change' its now something to do with a spatial frequency or something... Still a bit confused of the actual conceptual significance.

Comment: @SteveHatcher I also find it hard to find a clear physical interpretation for things in Fourier space. To me, it's often just a trick to turn differential equations into algebraic ones. In any case, one takes the inverse Fourier transform at the end to get back to real space, where one can interpret things more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Re: comments to the [accepted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130671/38551).

There is a very natural interpretation: **For a linear problem the Fourier transform is the same as a plane wave Ansatz**. That is, guess that $f(x) = c e^{-ikx}$ for some $k$, and put this into your equation. What you are doing is looking for solutions that are sinusoidal oscillations with a well-defined wavevector $k$. Clearly for such an $f$, you can set $\nabla \mapsto -ik$.

Some functional analysis guarantees that general function, with reasonable boundary conditions like $\int f^2 < \infty$, is expressible as a linear combination of plane waves, $$f(x) = \int dk\, c(k) e^{-ikx} $$
where it is more common to denote the coefficients $c(k)$ by $\hat f(k)$ or just $f(k)$. This formula defines the *inverse Fourier transform*, since one can show that (up to some factors $2\pi$) $$\hat f(k) = \int dx \, e^{ikx} f(x)$$
which is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

A Fourier transform can be done over spatial or temporal dimensions, but the end result is that $f(\mathbf{x},t)$ $\rightarrow$ $F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$.  The assumption is that the amplitude, $A$, of the signal is not dependent upon $\mathbf{k}$ or $\omega$, which allows one to say that $F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$ ~ $A \ e^{i (\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} - \omega t)}$.  Then one can see that $\nabla F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$ $\rightarrow$ $i \ \mathbf{k} \ F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$ and $\partial_{t} \ F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$ $\rightarrow$ -$i \ \omega \ F(\mathbf{k},\omega)$.

**Side Note**
This is often referred to as *linearizing* the equations or using a linear approximation of a fluctuating signal.  The distinction is used because a nonlinear wave can have $A$ = $A(\mathbf{k},\omega)$, though this is not strictly required for nonlinearity.